# Unable to disable generation of sources JAR with maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven-2, release, ear, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release a web project using Maven 2.2.1 and the maven-release-plugin 2.0-beta-9, but it always fails when doing release:perform on generating the sources jar for the EAR project, which makes sense since the EAR project doesn't have any source.

```
[INFO] [INFO] [source:jar {execution: attach-sources}]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Error creating source archive: You must set at least one file.
```

To try to disable the building of a sources JAR for the EAR project, I added the following to the POM for my EAR project (the version of the release plugin is set in a parent POM):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Upon running the release again after checking in this change, I got the same error while generating the sources JAR for the EAR project, even though this should have been disabled by the previous POM snippet.

What am I doing wrong?  Why is the sources JAR still being built?

**Edit**:
I've tried to make the source plugin include my application.xml file so that this error doesn't occur by adding the following POM snippet:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${basedir}/META-INF/**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem either.

Comment: Why are you using a 2.0-beta-9 of the maven-release-plugin ...2.0 exist..the release plugin is not the right way to prevent creation of source-jars...As far as i can remember an EAR needs some configuration/property files...(source files) ? may be i'm wrong...

Comment: I was using an old version of the release plugin partially because that was the version that the branch that is being released was developed against, and also because I didn't realize that v2.0 was out.

Comment: About the source files, for some reason the source plugin isn't picking up on the config files that you put in an EAR.

Comment: I've tried to configure the sources plugin to include my application.xml (in a non-standard directory), but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I needed to add my source files as part of the references:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>META-INF/**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>target/**/*</exclude>
            <exclude>bin/**/*</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/.svn/**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Doing this made everything work again.  I didn't need any special configuration for the release or source plugins to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the maven-source-plugin version 2.1 that resulted in the same error as you describe here. Newer Version >= 2.1.1 contain the fix. Here is a link to this Bug for further information. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSOURCES-44